# React Native - async/await does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to use async/await outside of classes?
For example I use AsyncStorage to store access token and want to get this token before StackNavigator will be initialized.

**container.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import PairingView from '../components/PairingView';
import MainView from '../components/MainView';
import { getTokenFromStorageAsync } from '../helpers/asyncStorageHelper';

const accessToken = getTokenFromStorageAsync().done();
console.log(accessToken);   <---------- undefined

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  PairingRoute: {
    screen: PairingView
  },
  MainRoute: {
    screen: MainView
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: (accessToken == null) ? 'PairingRoute' : 'MainRoute',
  initialRouteParams: {
    token: accessToken
  }
});

const App = () => (
  <AppNavigator />
);

export default App;
```

**asyncStorageHelper.js**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const getTokenFromStorageAsync = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@nfs:token');
    console.log(value);   <---------- access token
    if (value != null)
      return value;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  return undefined;
};
```

Comment: const accessToken = await getTokenFromStorageAsync();

Comment: @ponury-kostek await can be used only with async function

Comment: Sorry my mistake. So change it to getTokenFromStorageAsync().then(token => console.log(token));

Comment: `async/await` is part of this year's release (ES2017) not of last years release (ES7/ES2016). Please read tag descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      accessToken: 'fetching'
    };

    this._loadAccessToken();
  }

  _loadAccessToken = async () => {
    const token = await getTokenFromStorageAsync();
    this.setState({ accessToken: token });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.accessToken === 'fetching')
      return null;

    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
      PairingRoute: {
        screen: PairingView
      },
      MainRoute: {
        screen: MainView
      }
    }, {
      initialRouteName: (this.state.accessToken == null) ? 'PairingRoute' : 'MainRoute',
      initialRouteParams: {
        token: this.state.accessToken
      }
    });

    return <AppNavigator />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did to fix it?

Comment: @Noitidart so, in question i tried to get value from AsyncStorage outside of component. It will not work, because `await` can't be used without async function. I just move it inside component and do whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
getTokenFromStorageAsync().then(accessToken => {
    console.log(accessToken);
    // ...
});
```

or

```
// ...
export default (async () => {

    const accessToken = await getTokenFromStorageAsync();
    console.log(accessToken);

    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
      PairingRoute: {
        screen: PairingView
      },
      MainRoute: {
        screen: MainView
      }
    }, {
      initialRouteName: (accessToken == null) ? 'PairingRoute' : 'MainRoute',
      initialRouteParams: {
        token: accessToken
      }
    });

    const App = () => (
      <AppNavigator />
    );

    return App;

})()
```

As you can see you have to export a promise that resolves with your App, instead of exporting your App directly.

Edit:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/container';
(async () => {
    let ResolvedApp = await App()
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('someappname', () => ResolvedApp);
    // ...
})()
```

Comment: and how can it be used with AppNavigator?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You'll have to export a promise that resolves wihtout your `App` then.

Comment: as well as if i import `getTokenFromStorageAsync` as Promise. I want to do this without `.then` or `.done`.

Comment: Your getTokenFromStorageAsync returns a promise, too. Instead of then/done you can always use await.

Comment: yep, sorry. but how can i resolve App? I need to do this `AppRegistry.registerComponent('someappname', () => App);`

Comment: hmm... Does not work, error `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module`. I guess, AppRegistry should be synchronously

Comment: I don't think that error is related to the question anymore. Have you tried googleing it?

Comment: But with synchronous code it works good, guess the problem in async code

Comment: Can you please add the code that works to your question?

Comment: I don't have answer to my question, but code in question post works for me except token. Or I don't get it

Comment: I can't see `AppRegistry.registerComponent` in your question, why did you mention it?

Comment: Can you please add that main file to your question? At least the relevant parts (imports and call of `AppRegistry.registerComponent`).

Comment: It's main file, which register main component for app. Just have import AppRegistry from react-native component and import App, which i attached. `import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'; import App from './app/container';  AppRegistry.registerComponent('someappname', () => App);`

Comment: Tried at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718910/react-native-async-await-does-not-work/44719170?noredirect=1#comment76421375_44719170

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You linked to a comment that was written before I changed the code.

Comment: I modified this file before you :)