# Returning data from a promise in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, axios

In my react app I want to pass my data (transactions) into redux. To do that I've created this reducer:

```
import axios from 'axios'

let data = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/transactions')
  .then(res => {
    return res.data
  })

export default data
```

But when I get data to pass it to `combineReducers` I get this instead of an array that can be passed and used by components

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Array(10)
```

How can I extract that `Array(10)` ?

Comment: Via `promise.then(result => {/*do something with result*/})`. Promises do **not** make asynchronous process synchronous.

Comment: And that's not a reducer. You should do this in an action creator (probably using redux thunk) and update the state in a reducer.

Comment: check out this link, here it is more clearly explained: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718910/react-native-async-await-does-not-work